"beg, plead, entreat, implore, beseech, appeal" What is the different and when to use
Here is what I researched, is the meaning correct, and when to use
Please help me
1. Beg

ask for help, mercy, or forgiveness.
sometimes carry a connotation of weakness or dependency.

2. Plead

ask for mercy or leniency, especially in a legal context (like in court)

3. Entreat

to try very hard to persuade someone to do something.

4. Implore

ask someone to do or not do something in a very sincere, emotional, and determined way.

5. Beseech

ask for something in a way that shows you need it very much

6. Appeal

a request to the public for money, information, or help

This returns the same result when I translated it to Vietnamese through Google translate

Edit:
I found this website, it's about the difference between beg and plead.
It has 3 sections:

Definitions
List of Similarities,
What is the difference? (Formality, Legal context, Emotional tone, Specificity, Connotation)

It will be so helpful if these are a full difference of all the words above. Any help is appreciated

You should give a specific situation where you want the best word.

Few words have only one meaning. These words are obviously closely related, but as you note, there can be contexts in which only one is the right choice. E.g., you can talk about someone asking for money on the street by saying "he is begging," but the other words would not be clear choices. And in law "plead" and "appeal" have meanings in legal uses that could not take the other options. If you want to use one of these words in a real context, please edit to tell more about that context.

Also note: You can say "I beg you" and use the same pattern for entreat, implore, and beseech. But you can't say "I plead you"; it's an intransitive verb. And "appeal" needs the helper "to," "I appeal to you."

@AndyBonner thanks for the comments. I do not have a context here.  While I was surfing the internet I found these words. I'm just wondering about the use cases of each word. Maybe it is based on formality, intensity, frequency (like Astralbee answered below), or something detailed (your real-life example, ...).
Note: I am not good at English, I have tried my best to describe my question, please forgive me if I make some mistake.

I updated the question. I hope it good

That makes sense. Ultimately your best results will be to look each word up in a dictionary, where you will get all the senses and uses of each word.

This kind of question could attract different opinions. But, as all these words carry pretty much the same meaning, I think you should consider how and when to use them based on their formality and intensity.

Beg: This is a fairly common and informal word. It's used to request something urgently, often with a sense of desperation or need.

Plead: This is slightly more formal than "beg." It suggests a stronger appeal or request, often involving emotion or desperation.

Entreat: This is a formal word, suggesting a respectful or earnest request. It's commonly used in written or formal contexts.

Implore: This is a formal word as well, indicating a strong and urgent request. It's often used in serious or emotional situations.

Beseech: This is a highly formal word, suggesting a very earnest and urgent plea. It's commonly found in literature or formal speeches.

Appeal: This is also a formal word, but it's less intense than "beseech." It suggests a request made with reason or logic, often in a legal or official context.


So, in summary:
Least formal and intense: Beg
Increasing formality and intensity: Plead, Entreat, Implore
Most formal and intense: Beseech, Appeal

Thank you for the response. It's helpful, but I plan to offer a bounty if there's a better answer. I'll accept your answer if no better answer comes along.
